# Keras with Tensorflow backend---Memoryerror in model.fit() with checkpoint callbacks

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to train an autoencoder. It keeps getting Memoryerror from Keras at model.fit(), it always occurs when i add validation-related parameters to model.fit like validation_split.

**Error:**

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/root/abnormal-spatiotemporal-ae/start_train.py", line 53, in <module>
>     train(dataset=dataset, job_folder=job_folder, logger=logger)
>   File "/root/abnormal-spatiotemporal-ae/classifier.py", line 109, in train
>     callbacks=[snapshot, earlystop, history_log]
>   File "/root/anaconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
> ```
>
> line 990, in fit
>           y, val_y = (slice_arrays(y, 0, split_at),
>         File "/root/anaconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py",
>   line 528, in slice_arrays
>           return [None if x is None else x[start:stop] for x in arrays]
>         File "/root/anaconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py",
>   line 528, in 
>           return [None if x is None else x[start:stop] for x in arrays]
>         File "/root/anaconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/utils/io_utils.py",
>   line 110, in **getitem**
>           return self.data[idx]
>         File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
>         File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
>         File "/root/anaconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/h5py/_hl/dataset.py",
>   line 485, in **getitem**
>           arr = numpy.ndarray(mshape, new_dtype, order='C')
>       MemoryError

**Code:**

```
data = HDF5Matrix(os.path.join(video_root_path, '{0}/{0}_train_t{1}.h5'.format(dataset, time_length)),
                  'data')

snapshot = ModelCheckpoint(os.path.join(job_folder,
           'model_snapshot_e{epoch:03d}_{val_loss:.6f}.h5'))
earlystop = EarlyStopping(patience=10)
history_log = LossHistory(job_folder=job_folder, logger=logger)

logger.info("Initializing training...")

history = model.fit(
    data,
    data,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    epochs=nb_epoch,
    validation_split=0.15,
    shuffle='batch',
    callbacks=[snapshot, earlystop, history_log]
)
```

The code will run correctly when i remove validation_split=0.15 in model.fit and snapshot in callbacks.

data variable contains all processed images from training dataset,
its shape is (15200, 8, 224, 224, 1) and size is 6101401600
This code is used on computer with 64GB RAM and a Tesla P100, no worry for memory space, and my python is 64-bit

**Model:**

```
input_tensor = Input(shape=(t, 224, 224, 1))

    conv1 = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(11, 11), padding='same', strides=(4, 4), name='conv1'),
                            input_shape=(t, 224, 224, 1))(input_tensor)
    conv1 = TimeDistributed(BatchNormalization())(conv1)
    conv1 = TimeDistributed(Activation('relu'))(conv1)

    conv2 = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(5, 5), padding='same', strides=(2, 2), name='conv2'))(conv1)
    conv2 = TimeDistributed(BatchNormalization())(conv2)
    conv2 = TimeDistributed(Activation('relu'))(conv2)

    convlstm1 = ConvLSTM2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', return_sequences=True, name='convlstm1')(conv2)
    convlstm2 = ConvLSTM2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', return_sequences=True, name='convlstm2')(convlstm1)
    convlstm3 = ConvLSTM2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', return_sequences=True, name='convlstm3')(convlstm2)

    deconv1 = TimeDistributed(Conv2DTranspose(128, kernel_size=(5, 5), padding='same', strides=(2, 2), name='deconv1'))(convlstm3)
    deconv1 = TimeDistributed(BatchNormalization())(deconv1)
    deconv1 = TimeDistributed(Activation('relu'))(deconv1)

    decoded = TimeDistributed(Conv2DTranspose(1, kernel_size=(11, 11), padding='same', strides=(4, 4), name='deconv2'))(
        deconv1)
```

Comment: Please provide information on your model.

Comment: Why do you provide `data` to your fit model twice?

Comment: You should try doing the train/val split yourself, instead of Keras doing it. Seems that you use too much RAM and doing the split itself requires more than available.

Comment: because the output of autoencoder is also t silces of picture---reconstructed. It tends to reconstruct the training dataset with small loss

Comment: After doing split by myself, it works, thank you for your comment!

Comment: Just a general advice, running your code as root is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40757232/4153034) faced the same problem. Here the explanation was, that there were too much data points before the flattening layer. This caused the RAM to overflow. This was solved by adding additional convolution layer.

Comment: It can work if i don't add validation_split-related parameters for model.fit, which means RAM can handle these data. Is my understanding right?